# IntelliSense при написании разметки

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, intellisense

Когда пишу разметку в visual studio в приложениях на wpf, то заметил, что нет автодополнения в тех случаях когда пишу свойства, например здесь[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. я хочу указать свойство `FontSize` например у кнопки, но приходится вручную дописывать. Так как не так давно пишу код, то не всегда знаю, где находится это свойство. 
Вот вопрос в том, можно ли как-то это поправить или все с этим живут?

Comment: Попробуй `Ctrl` + `J`

Comment: @Nikita К сожалению не помогает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите тип вашего контрола:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BigFontButton">
    ...
```

[image: скриншотики, скриншотики не забываем!]

Без него как Visual Studio узнает, что ваш тип для кнопки, и как сможет предложить нужные свойства?

Comment: Указываю `TargetType="Button"`, но у сеттера мне надо установить `Property="Control.FontFamily"` . Вот собственно, когда начинаю писать `Control` нет никакого автодополнения.

Comment: @alladuh: А почему не просто `Property="FontFamily"`?

Comment: Хорошее замечание. Просто я рассматриваю примеры из книги и там так было приведено. 
А если я решу применить этот стиль не только к тексту кнопки, а например ещё какому-то тексту, а у меня указан `TargetType="Button"`, стиль же тогда не применится к этому элементу?

Comment: @alladuh: Нет, будет ошибка времени выполнения. Но если вы хотите применять к тексту, то имеет смысл создавать либо отдельный стиль для текста, либо стиль для «общего предка». В любом случае, указывать тип имеет смысл почти всегда.

Comment: Кажется разобрался, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @alladuh: Пожалуйста!